# Sign-in with Google gmail

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

Having a problem with signing in with Google. Trying to use it in Ruby on Rails and JavaScript with the `devise` gem. I made the registration in the Google console but so far nothing worked. I'm getting an `OAuth::Unauthorized` error.

```
# app/controllers/callbacks_controller.rb

def redirect
  client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
    client_id: ENV.fetch('Google ID'),
    client_secret: ENV.fetch('Google secret'),
    authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    scope: Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_READONLY,
    redirect_uri: url_for(:action => :callback)
  })

  redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
end

def callback
  client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
    client_id: ENV.fetch('Google ID'),
    client_secret: ENV.fetch('Google secret'),
    token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    redirect_uri: url_for(:action => :callback),
    code: params[:code]
  })

  response = client.fetch_access_token!

  session[:access_token] = response['access_token']

  redirect_to url_for(:action => :labels)
end

# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

def googleAuth

  access_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.from_omniauth(access_token)
  log_in(user)

  user.google_token = access_token.credentials.token

  refresh_token = access_token.credentials.refresh_token
  user.google_refresh_token = refresh_token if refresh_token.present?
  user.save
  redirect_to root_path
end

# config/initializers/ominauth.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['google id'],
  ENV['google secret']
end

# Gemfile

gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.9', require: 'google/apis/gmail_v1'

# config/routes.rb

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }

get "auth/:provider/callback", to: "sessions#googleAuth"
get "auth/failure", to: redirect("/")

# app/model/user.rb

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
       :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google]

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
end
```

I want my users to be able to sign up and login by using their gmail accounts.
Probably after trying everything made my code a little messy and sure there is a better and cleaner solution that I could not find yet.

Comment: `It is having the "OAuth::Unauthorized" problem` be more specific, what's "the OAuth::Unauthorized problem"? when does that happend? If you have an error show it, if you have the server log show it. Start by debugging each step of the code to reduce the scope of the real problem (first make sure the initial redirect is right, than check the response on the callback it may have some more descriptive error, then the next step and so on).

Comment: When i try "sign-in with Google" i am having... OAuth::Unauthorized
404 Not Found
Extracted source (around line #236):
234
235
236
237
238
239
              
        self.token_request(http_method, uri.path, token, request_options, arguments)
      when (400..499)
        raise OAuth::Unauthorized, response
      else
        response.error!
      end

Rails.root: /Users/as/code/elifmentes/moh

Comment: Have you set the environment variables right? you use both `ENV['Google ID']` and `ENV['google id`]` and I guess it's case sensitive. Also check the official guide, it has an example using ruby+sinatra but the code inside the actions should mostly work for Rails too https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer